# Using layer.cornerRadius leaves squared corners visible

Tags: iphone, xcode, quartz-graphics

Look at this picture[image]

I've set its layer.cornerRadius to 15.0 and its layer.borderWidth to 2.0. So i really have such a frame with rounded corners but as you can see squared corners remain visible. They're visible slightly here but in my application they're visible really distinctively. What should i do to make them invisible?

Comment: Why is the image quality so bad? It looks like it's been scaled somehow. Is this really the 1:1 result you get on the iPhone? Because the border looks way too ugly for a CALayer border. Or is the border already present in the image? Last but not least, have you set the `backgroundColor` to a transparent color, like `[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]`?

Comment: this image is just an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you put 
view.opaque = NO

view.clipsToBounds = YES

?

Comment: This should have been a comment, since it definitely isn't an answer.

Comment: @DarkDust It seems to be the answer after all ;)